# How to post Action result to Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In a MVC view, i  have 2 forms with as many fields like bellow

LoginRegisterModel.cs

```
public class LoginRegisterViewModel {
    public string LoginUsername { get; set; }
    public string LoginPassword { get; set; }

    public string RegisterUsername { get; set; }
    public string RegisterPassword { get; set; }
    public string RegisterFirstName { get; set; }
    public string RegisterLastName { get; set; }
}
```

LoginRegistte.cshtml  (1st form)

```
@model LoginRegisterViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "MemeberController", FormMethod.Post, new {})) {

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginUsername)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginUsername)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginPassword)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginPassword)

    <input type='Submit' value='Login' />

}
```

2nd form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "MemeberController", FormMethod.Post, new {})) {

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterFirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterFirstName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterLastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterLastName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterUsername)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterUsername)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterPassword)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterPassword)

    <input type='Submit' value='Register' />
```

}

MemberController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoginRegister() {
     LoginRegisterViewModel model = new LoginRegisterViewModel();
     return view("LoginRegister", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginRegisterViewModel model) {
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
 //some logic
  }
         else
          {

                   return view(model);
                      }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(LoginRegisterViewModel model) {
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
 //some logic
   }
         else
          {

                   return view(model);
                      }
}
```

in this when i am directly click on 1st form button that time i want fire validations for 1st form.but i am getting two forms validations at a time. what i do in controller or some where else?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

**Form1**

```
@model LoginRegisterViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "MemeberController", FormMethod.Post, new {id="frmLogin"})) {

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginUsername)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginUsername)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginPassword)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginPassword)

    <input type='Submit' value='Login' id="btnLogin" />

}
```

**Form2**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "MemeberController", FormMethod.Post, new {id="frmRegister"})) {

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterFirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterFirstName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterLastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterLastName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterUsername)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterUsername)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterPassword)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterPassword)

    <input type='Submit' value='Register' id= "btnRegister" />
}
```

**Script**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#btnLogin').click(function () {

           var validation = $("#frmLogin"); 
                       if (!validation.valid()) {
                         return false;
                        }

});

 $('#btnRegister').click(function () {

           var validationRegi = $("#frmRegister"); 
                       if (!validationRegi.valid()) {
                         return false;
                        }

});
});
```

Comment: i need code for controller action.how to write? else i am taken above script but how to write controller action for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just a typo here:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "MemeberController", FormMethod.Post, new {}))
```

MemeberController should be MemberController.

It is in 2 spots, so make sure you catch both of them.